# Developing Android Apps with PHP?

Tags: php, android

I'm looking for a way (platform perhaps) that would let me run my PHP based 
application on the Android (with actually being production-ready).

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Try check out 'paw' application

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Android Scripting Environment, a lot of the work can be tested and edited right on your device. Find more info here: http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html